# I have a nopcommerce checkout page issue. After adding products to the cart and checking out it again goes to the cart page. How do i resolve this

Tags: database, networking, nopcommerce

I have a nopcommerce "checkout" page issue. After adding products to the cart and checking out it again goes to the cart page. How do i resolve this..

Tried adding products to the cart and tried checkout option. and it redirects to the shopping cart page rather checking out.

Comment: It's hard to say what could be the issue! couple of questions, 1) which version of nop? 2) Did you make any code changes? 3) which db you are using?

Comment: ThnQ for the prompt reply. 1) which version of nop? - nopCommerce 4.60.2
2) Did you make any code changes? -  No
3) which db you are using? -Mysql (mariadb)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post and your comments, it looks like you may have the Checkout disabled option selected. When it's selected nopCommerce will redirect back to the cart when you try to checkout.

Under the admin options ensure the Checkout disabled option is not selected.

To find the setting navigate the following...

Admin > Configuration > Settings > Order Settings

... and uncheck the option 'Checkout disabled'

[nopCommerce Order Mgmt Settings](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/running-your-store/order-management/order-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error happen in the checkout process. Check the application log (Admin/Log/List) filter by error, you will see the error.